# Is there a mathematical notion of "why"?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, philosophy

Is there a mathematical notion of "why"? That is, are there reasons behind the truth of certain mathematical statements? Personally, my belief is that true mathematical statements just are true. There are no reasons behind them. In fact, the notion of "reasons why a certain mathematical statement is true" does not even make sense to me. But perhaps some mathematician or philosopher has rigorously defined a notion of "why". If so, I would like to see such a text.

Comment: I mean, mathematical things are true if we can successfully deduce them from the given axioms.  What else could there be?

Comment: Sounds like an epistemological question.

Comment: there is a thing called a proof. What do you mean by "why"? Do you mean as in a proximate cause (grand underlying reason for the truth of a statement) or the immediate preceding one (if P, then Q, then Y, then Z, then W...)such as in a proof?

Comment: Are you talking about logic?

Comment: If you are asking for a mathematical proof that there is a reason for the existence of...well, anything...then I think you are out of luck.

Comment: "Tiger got to hunt, bird got to fly; Man got to sit and wonder, ‘Why, why, why?’ Tiger got to sleep, bird got to land; Man got to tell himself he understand." - Kurt Vonnegut

Comment: What does "why" mean *outside* mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

One idea comes from Plato's world of *forms* (see Plato's Republic), that the reason we can reason about things logically is because our cognition dips into this world of forms. For example, we don't really deal with circles in this world, only approximations, but that in the cognitive world of forms our minds can grasp a real circle, the form of the circle and that reasoning about circles is just our minds exploring this world of forms.

The *why* of mathematical truth is thus: because there exists a cognitive world of forms we can dip into. But then, *why* does such a world exist?
There are lots of ideas, but none of them are satisfying in that we feel like we have reached a bottom ground fundemental truth that all other truths are built on. Perhaps that bottom ground fundemental truth is just that things are because they are, as proposed.